# Детальная настройка Datepicker 'a php\yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Есть задача реализовать DatePicker на yii2. Там будет много нюансов по выбору даты которые либо подтягиваются из БД, либо должны быть прописаны на стороне сервера. 
Т.е. ковырять JS не вариант.
С yii2 только начал знакомство, и увидел что там есть возможность подключения виджета jQueri UI DatePicker.
Вопрос: предусматривает ли yii2 детальную настройку этого datepicker'a или лучше забить на этот виджет и писать свой?

Comment: свой вы хотите писать на пхп что ли без js ? или что? Если нет, то берите пикер из jquery или бутстрапа и настраивайте как надо. сайты без js делали 15 лет назад.

Comment: @teran, я просто не работал до этого ни с yii2 ни дэйтпикерами, и не могу понять как его настраивать. Ну например - мне нужно сделать определённую дату неактивной. Как это сделать в js я примерно понимаю. Сами даты у нас ведь генерируются на стороне js? Но как это сделать из php(или конкретно из yii2) ?

Comment: а в чем сложно то? в шаблонах html генерите какой то? js-там же можеет вывести, с json-массивом нужных дат и пропихнуть его в пикер? или запросить аяксом с сервера.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Установите себе datepicker от [kartik'a](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/datepicker) и будет вам счастье